# Data import from data loader: maintaining the hierarchy on Account records

Tags: data-loader, account

I have some accounts where ParentId is null which I want to populate. Here is my csv sample data

[image]

So I want the record to be associated with Account1 which has ExternalId__c as "4ab1dc5e-24cc-1405". Let's say that Account name is Account2 so I need Account1's ParentId as Account2's Id.

While doing the upsert I am selecting

```
The field for matching on Account: ExternalId__c
choosing related object: Parent -> ExternalId__c
```

Then in mapping screen:

```
ExternalId__c -> ExternalId__c
parent_id -> Parent:ExternalId__c
```

the result says successful but the ParentId of Account1 record is not populated with Account2's Id.

Can anyone help, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could be a stupid question, have you marked `ExternalId__c` field as External Id?

Comment: @Raul Yes, that's why the field is appearing in "select the field for matching on Account" as I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The `ParentId` on `Account1` won't have been set because it refers to the ID of `Account2` in the source org, not the org we're upserting into. `Account2` might not even exist at the time `Account1` is created, meaning there's no record to set the `ParentId` to.

To workaround this, you'll need to do a few steps:

1. Upsert the Accounts without `ParentId`, creating `Account1` and `Account2` in the target.
2. Create a new CSV containing the `Id` field and the `ParentId`, where these ID fields are the IDs created in step 1, not the IDs from the source org.
3. Update the Accounts with this new CSV file, to set the `ParentId` on `Account1`.

---

If you have records with the `ParentId` set in a Salesforce org, Gearset has a data deployment feature which allows you to do all of this in one operation. Full disclosure: I'm a software engineer at [Gearset](https://gearset.com/).

It does this by breaking the operation into a few parts:

1. Fetch Account records which match a filter (or up to 30,000 records).
2. Fetch any Account records which are parents of the records in step 1.
3. Upsert the Account records without setting the `ParentId`.
4. Update the Account records to set the `ParentId` field.

This is the same as the method described above, but you don't need to worry about IDs yourself.

There's a [30 day free trial](https://app.gearset.com/create-account) if you'd like to give Gearset a go. Feel free to get in touch if you have any questions!

Here's a summary of how to do the deployment in Gearset.

Select the source org (which has the `ParentId` set) and the target org (which has a `null` `ParentId`).

[image: Select the source and target org]

Select the `Account` object. You can optionally filter which Account records will be deployed if you're only interested in deploying a subset of the records.

[image: Select the Account object]

Select `upsert records` for Account and choose `ExternalId__c` as the field. This external id must exist in both the source and target org.

[image: Upsert Account using your external id field]

Click to deploy. Gearset will fetch any Account records matched by your filter (or up to 30,000 records if there was no filter) and any Account records which are a parent of those initial records. Gearset will then upsert all of these Account records, and update the records to set the `ParentId`.

[image: Gearset will upsert Account records and set the ParentId]

Answer (score 1):

Data Loader cannot do this in one pass because the the parent account may be in a later  group of records that is inserted, so the ID won't be available for earlier groups.

You have to do the insert first and ignore the ParentId.  Then you upsert the resulting success file, map the newly created account ID to the ID field in Salesforce, and map the csv external ID field to the ParentId field in Salesforce.